# Cannot find symbol : when compiling java code

Tags: java

I am writing some Java classes to implement RMI. I wrote all the classes and the program worked fine. But from the very next day I am getting a compiler error indicating that the absence of files:

Filename: **ServerInterface.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface ServerInterface extends Remote
{
  public double sum(double[] temp) throws RemoteException; 
};
```

Filename: **ServerImplement.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class ServerImplement extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface
{

 public ServerImplement() throws RemoteException 
 { 
 }

 public double sum(double[] temp) throws RemoteException
 {
   double sum=0;
   int len=temp.length;
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
     sum+=temp[i];

   return sum;
 }
};
```

Even to prove that its not any filename errors:

```
F:\E\java\rmi final>dir
 Volume in drive F is My Volume
 Volume Serial Number is E0F9-4F89

 Directory of F:\E\java\rmi final

22-01-2011  23:23    <DIR>          .
22-01-2011  23:23    <DIR>          ..
22-12-2009  13:09             1,849 additionImplementer_Stub.class
21-01-2011  21:52             1,076 Client.class
18-01-2011  02:54               649 Client.java
21-01-2011  21:52             1,847 ClientTry.class
18-01-2011  02:54             1,268 ClientTry.java
21-01-2011  21:52               444 ServerImplement.class
18-01-2011  02:30               386 ServerImplement.java
18-01-2011  02:54             1,783 ServerImplement_Stub.class
21-01-2011  21:54               209 ServerInterface.class
22-12-2009  12:07               132 ServerInterface.java
21-01-2011  21:52               919 ServerMain.class
18-01-2011  02:36               409 ServerMain.java
          12 File(s)         10,971 bytes
```

If I try: `javac *.java` , it works fine (but trying java on any of the .class files leads to error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServerMain`

If I try `javac ServerImplement.java` I get an error (in fact none of my java programs are able to link):
(I am in the same directory)

> E:\java\rmi final>javac  ServerMain.java
>   ServerImplement.java:4: cannot find symbol
>   `symbol: class ServerInterface`
>   `public class ServerImplement extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface`
>   `^`
>   `1 error`

The program is even working fine at my college lab. Should I reinstall JDK? Or is there any way to provide linking explicitly?

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild.

Comment: How to do that with command prompt??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have "." on the classpath. Try to run it like this:

```
java -classpath . ServerMain
```

Have a look at your CLASSPATH environment variable to see if that's getting in the way - these days I typically find it's easiest not to have one, to be honest.

Comment: I have my environment variable set: CLASSPATH="c:/...../bin" Do I still need to do this??

Comment: Yes. Also ensure that you're in command prompt currently sitting in the folder with those classes (and assuming that they indeed don't have `package` declarations -which is a poor practice anyway, but that aside).

Comment: n what does this mean?? And I didnt write any such stuff before(when the program worked fine) :-/

Comment: @smartmuki, change that to "C:/.../bin;."

Comment: @smartnuki: you have 2 feasible options: 1) **remove** the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. It will then default to current working directory (the folder where you're currently sitting in the command prompt). 2) Add `-classpath .` argument as told by Jon (or shorter, `-cp .`). Third option is to add `.` to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, but I wouldn't recommend using it at all. It only leads to more and more confusion among starters and might break portability of your application to other machines.

Answer (score 0):

There is no linking when compiling java code.
The compiler still needs to find all classes that are referenced by the code being compiled.
If you don't use packages, make sure you run javac in the same directory your .java is in. A javac *.java should be able to resolve your problems.